# Mass Edit Sortable VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, standardcontroller

We are trying to implement a mass edit type VF page that displays a few fields in a list and allows the user to edit one of those fields. We have a requirement that the list be sortable by column. I’ve taken examples from SFDC and pieced together an implementation using an extension class to do the sorting and the standardsetcontroller. The problem we are having is once a user makes edits to the data on the page and presses the Save button, their changes are not saved; When I examine the records the user supposedly edited I see no changes. Moreover, the debug logs do not indicate any updates were done.  What do I need to do to get my VF page to Save (update) the records the user has edited?

Here is our VF Page:

```
    <apex:pageMessage summary="Selected Collection Size: {!selectedSize}" 
        severity="info"
        id="mupms"
    />
    <apex:pageMessage summary="Record Set Size: {!recordsSize}"
        severity="info"
        id="mupmr"
    />

    <apex:pageBlock title="Ticket Mass-Update" mode="edit" id="mub1">
        <apex:pageMessages />

        <apex:pageBlockSection id="mus1">
            <apex:inputField value="{!Ticket1__Ticket__c.Status__c}" id="status">
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="muselectedlist"/>
            </apex:inputField>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom" id="mubut">
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" id="butsav"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" id="butcan"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:pageBlock title="Campaign Tickets" id="muselectedlist">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!tickets}" var="tix" id="mutab">

            <apex:column >
                <apex:outputText value="{!tix.Id}" />
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column >
                <apex:outputText value="{!tix.Name}" />
            </apex:column>                

            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:commandLink action="{!sort}" value="Ticket1__tix_LastName__c{!IF(sorterUtil.column=='Ticket1__tix_LastName__c',IF(sorterUtil.sortDirection='ASC','?','?'),'')}">
                        <apex:param value="Ticket1__tix_LastName__c" name="column" assignTo="{!sorterUtil.column}" ></apex:param>
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:facet>
                <apex:outputText value="{!tix.Ticket1__tix_LastName__c}" />
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:commandLink action="{!sort}" value="Ticket1__tix_FirstName__c{!IF(sorterUtil.column=='Ticket1__tix_FirstName__c',IF(sorterUtil.sortDirection='ASC','?','?'),'')}">
                        <apex:param value="Ticket1__tix_FirstName__c" name="column" assignTo="{!sorterUtil.column}" ></apex:param>
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:facet>
                <apex:outputText value="{!tix.Ticket1__tix_FirstName__c}" />
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:commandLink action="{!sort}" value="Attendee_Role__c{!IF(sorterUtil.column=='Attendee_Role__c',IF(sorterUtil.sortDirection='ASC','?','?'),'')}">
                        <apex:param value="Attendee_Role__c" name="column" assignTo="{!sorterUtil.column}" ></apex:param>
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:facet>
                <apex:outputText value="{!tix.Attendee_Role__c}" />
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:commandLink action="{!sort}" value="Status__c{!IF(sorterUtil.column=='Status__c',IF(sorterUtil.sortDirection='ASC','?','?'),'')}">
                        <apex:param value="Status__c" name="column" assignTo="{!sorterUtil.column}" ></apex:param>
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:facet>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!tix.Status__c}"/>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Here is our controller:

```
public class SortingController { 
//[Select Id, Name, Tickets1__tix_LastName__c, Tickets1__tix_FirstName__c, Attendee_Role__c, Status__c From Tickets1__Ticket__c];

private final ApexPages.StandardSetController cntr;
String qid;

private String defaultSortColumn = 'Tickets1__tix_LastName__c'; /** Set the default sort Column. /
private String sortDirection = 'ASC';
public SortingControllerUtil sorterUtil {get; set;} /* Declare Sorter Utility class Object. /

public SortingController(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {

 qid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
 system.debug('Id of object in context is=' + qid);

 cntr = (ApexPages.StandardSetController)controller;

 sorterUtil = new SortingControllerUtil(defaultSortColumn, sortDirection); /* Create Sorter_UTIL Object. /
}
public List<Tickets1__Ticket__c> getTickets() {
 /* Add the column and sort direction value at the end of query.*/
 String stringQuery =
  'Select Id, Name, Tickets1__tix_LastName__c, Tickets1__tix_FirstName__c, Attendee_Role__c, Status__c From Tickets1__Ticket__c ' +
  'Where Tickets1__tix_Campaign__c= :qid ' + 
  'Order By ' + sorterUtil.getColumn() + ' ' + sorterUtil.getSortDirection() +' NULLS LAST';
 return database.query(stringQuery);
}

public PageReference sort() { /* Define sorting method. **/
 /** Do nothing here. **/
 return null;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined get for list, please try define also set.

set for your list

```
yourListOfObjects{ set;} //
```

And mayby use custom save method.

```
public void save(){
    update yourListOfObjects;
}
```

Also if I may ask why standard controller is final in your class?

Comment: Very Helpful - thank you! We were able to get this working based on both suggestions on our post.

Answer (score 1):

Name the function something other than "Save" (and change "!save" on your VF page).  Your call to "Save" is ending up in the standard controller, not your extension.

Below is some code I use to do something similar.  In this case I delete the selected records.

```
public PageReference processSelected() {
List<Offdays__c> selectedOffdays = new List<Offdays__c>();

// get the list of selected off days
    for(SiteOffday od: getOffdays()) {
        if(od.toDelete == true) {
            selectedOffdays.add(od.OffDay);
        }
    }

    //delete the selected off days.
    if (selectedOffdays.size() > 0) {
    delete selectedOffdays;
    }

FindOffdays();
return null;
}
```

Comment: Very Helpful - thank you! We were able to get this working based on both suggestions on our post.

Answer (score 0):

Simulating the behaviour of Salesforce Standard UI is hard, especially when it comes to table behaviour. A while ago I had similar problem when I worked on a configurable **[Visualforce TableGrid](https://github.com/Up2Go/visualforce-table-grid)** component. I recently made it open source on Github.

Maybe you want to check the source code of the `TableGridController` and how it delegated the sorting to the underlying `StandardSetController`.

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution Robert, although we were able to get the sorting to work, we were not able to get mass editing to work - we will take a closer look when time allows to see if your solution will help us out. Thanks again!

Comment: @RavinSunkiller If you like my post you can vote it up ;-)